# macOS|Unix combine multi-line .txt file into single line with no spaces? (no line breaks)

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, regex

I've been looking around & I cannot seem to find a command or regex that will do a simple command of combing all linebreaks & spaces in a text file into one line. most of them either add some kind of separator or a line break which I do not want.

I want to turn:

```
save>
  <version>0.6</version>
  <currentScene>ar_0000_WorldMap</currentScene>
  <saveTime>20200920T08:06:13+2</saveTime>
  <gameplaytime>0</gameplaytime>
  <difficulty>3</difficulty>
  <ironManMode>False</ironManMode>
  <permanentDeath>False</permanentDeath>
  <hideSkillRequirements>False</hideSkillRequirements>
  <friendlyFire>True</friendlyFire>
  <cameraZoom>0</cameraZoom>
  <selectedPc>0</selectedPc>
  <time>0</time>
  <money>666</money>
  <levels>
    <level>
      <name>ar_m2001_AmbushSite</name>
      <fow>148;0208;11;08;15;0242;11;0255;11;0255;11;04;126;01;14;0220;11;04;132;0219;11;03;133;0219;11;03;132;0220;11;02;133;0220;11;02;131;0222;11;02;131;0222;11;02;132;0221;135;0221;136;0220;12;02;11;01;129;0221;11;03;131;0221;132;02;12;0220;132;02;12;0220;132;02;11;0221;132;0224;131;012;18;0205;131;012;15;0208;131;012;15;0208;130;013;15;0208;11;03;120;019;16;0207;11;03;120;01;14;014;14;0209;11;03;120;01;13;015;14;0209;11;03;120;01;12;016;14;0209;11;03;117;04;12;015;162;01;16;0145;11;03;117;04;11;015;171;0144;11;04;115;01;12;017;14;05;155;0152;11;05;110;023;15;04;11;03;16;02;144;08;11;0143;11;03;18;026;175;0143;11;03;14;02;12;025;177;0142;11;03;14;028;178;0142;11;03;14;027;174;01;14;0142;11;03;14;026;117;01;157;01;15;0141;11;03;14;026;175;01;15;0141;11;03;14;025;182;0141;12;02;14;024;177;01;16;0140;13;01;18;020;177;01;16;0140;13;01;18;019;178;01;16;0140;13;01;18;019;178;01;16;0140;13;01;18;018;186;0140;13;01;112;014;186;0140;13;01;112;013;187;0142;11;01;112;013;187;0144;112;013;187;0145;17;016;188;0148;14;016;188;0168;188;0168;188;0167;112;02;11;02;172;0167;18;01;11;03;13;01;172;0167;18;03;14;02;171;0168;115;02;171;0168;16;03;179;0168;16;03;178;046;112;0111;18;01;178;040;118;0111;188;036;121;0111;19;01;12;01;175;033;123;05;11;013;11;092;16;04;12;01;175;031;126;04;11;013;12;091;18;02;12;01;175;029;126;06;18;06;12;091;18;02;178;027;142;06;12;091;19;01;16;01;171;026;142;07;12;011;12;078;116;01;171;024;144;07;12;010;14;076;117;01;171;023;145;08;11;09;16;075;189;022;147;07;11;09;17;073;190;020;149;07;11;08;19;072;190;018;152;06;11;07;111;070;191;016;154;01;12;03;11;07;112;069;191;015;158;02;12;06;113;068;19;01;182;013;166;04;114;067;19;01;182;012;167;03;116;066;19;02;180;012;159;01;12;02;123;065;12;02;188;011;160;01;12;02;122;066;192;010;160;02;12;02;121;067;192;09;163;04;119;068;192;09;145;03;116;04;119;068;192;08;146;04;111;01;13;04;117;070;192;07;146;07;17;03;12;05;115;072;116;01;174;08;145;010;15;03;11;06;113;01;11;072;116;01;174;07;145;026;111;076;147;01;143;06;146;026;12;085;147;01;142;07;146;026;17;083;116;02;126;01;142;07;122;01;122;013;18;06;15;086;114;01;11;01;168;06;11;01;122;01;16;01;119;09;18;07;121;05;11;059;117;02;170;05;120;02;124;02;12;03;116;06;122;02;14;064;111;01;171;06;120;01;13;05;145;02;127;064;114;01;168;05;120;03;11;02;11;02;16;01;112;01;126;02;127;064;114;01;167;06;119;07;118;05;126;02;11;01;125;059;11;01;11;01;128;01;153;06;115;014;147;02;11;01;125;059;132;01;126;01;126;06;18;01;13;03;12;06;11;03;115;02;132;02;11;01;125;058;115;01;117;01;115;01;110;01;125;07;17;03;11;04;12;04;121;02;132;02;11;01;125;057;134;01;127;03;121;07;18;03;11;07;11;01;121;03;132;02;11;01;125;057;118;02;114;01;127;03;120;08;18;03;11;08;15;01;115;02;134;02;11;01;125;056;118;01;135;01;130;09;18;03;11;03;13;02;17;01;148;04;120;03;13;056;117;02;136;01;128;09;19;03;12;02;13;05;13;03;146;04;121;05;11;055;156;01;127;010;19;03;12;010;13;03;147;03;121;05;11;055;134;01;148;011;19;03;12;010;13;03;148;03;120;05;11;054;184;011;110;02;12;09;11;01;11;02;11;01;149;02;13;077;116;01;136;02;129;011;112;01;11;011;155;01;16;074;115;01;136;02;130;011;116;09;164;071;152;01;132;011;117;08;158;01;11;02;12;071;115;01;136;01;132;011;117;06;15;01;158;01;15;02;11;064;152;01;132;011;117;07;13;02;159;01;14;066;153;01;132;011;121;03;13;01;161;02;12;066;153;01;132;011;122;03;11;03;12;01;157;03;11;04;12;060;185;012;123;09;159;06;14;058;152;01;132;012;122;010;160;05;15;057;151;01;133;012;121;011;161;04;14;058;151;01;132;013;121;011;161;05;13;058;151;01;132;013;120;012;162;05;12;058;183;015;119;012;162;016;11;048;183;015;117;014;163;015;11;048;111;01;170;017;115;010;12;03;163;015;11;048;111;02;169;017;113;012;14;01;161;01;12;014;11;048;111;02;134;01;133;018;112;014;14;01;11;02;157;066;110;03;133;02;133;019;110;016;13;03;11;01;156;066;110;03;133;02;132;020;110;016;13;04;16;02;149;066;110;02;134;02;132;021;15;01;13;011;11;011;11;01;15;01;153;061;111;02;134;02;131;022;12;01;11;03;11;012;12;03;11;03;164;061;111;01;136;02;129;045;13;01;12;01;164;060;150;01;129;044;173;059;179;035;121;01;16;02;156;056;166;02;111;035;129;02;157;053;168;01;111;035;124;01;14;02;159;08;11;042;165;01;115;034;113;03;113;02;161;049;159;04;13;02;114;033;130;01;162;047;159;06;11;02;116;032;130;01;164;045;160;05;11;01;118;032;121;01;173;044;160;05;121;031;198;040;163;01;13;03;117;031;1100;038;169;02;117;031;1101;036;169;03;117;030;1103;034;132;01;136;03;117;030;1104;033;170;03;117;030;1105;031;171;01;117;031;1106;030;119;01;152;01;118;029;1107;029;131;01;141;01;115;025;119;01;194;028;131;01;158;021;123;03;192;027;131;01;157;019;128;01;193;026;131;01;157;017;129;01;195;025;131;01;158;01;12;011;1127;025;190;02;11;09;1130;024;193;08;1132;023;191;08;1134;023;191;07;1136;022;127;01;164;05;1137;022;127;01;165;03;1139;021;126;02;165;02;1140;022;126;01;1208;021;126;01;1208;021;126;02;1207;021;126;02;1208;020;126;02;1208;020;126;02;191;01;1116;020;126;02;1209;019;126;02;1209;019;116;01;19;03;1208;019;115;04;17;04;11;01;172;02;1131;019;116;04;17;03;13;01;171;01;1131;019;118;02;18;02;13;04;168;01;1132;019;117;02;116;03;164;01;1134;019;117;02;182;03;1133;019;117;02;180;06;1132;020;116;01;178;09;1132;020;116;02;176;05;11;08;1128;020;120;01;171;08;11;01;12;03;12;01;18;02;1116;021;119;01;154;03;114;04;11;02;16;02;12;01;18;02;1116;021;119;03;154;01;114;04;11;03;115;01;1120;022;118;03;150;02;117;08;1136;022;120;01;170;01;11;04;1137;023;119;05;143;01;123;03;117;01;1121;023;120;05;143;01;123;02;1139;024;123;02;142;01;123;02;1139;025;121;02;169;02;1137;025;128;01;161;04;1137;026;177;02;110;05;1135;028;188;04;1136;029;186;01;1140;030;185;02;1138;032;184;02;11;05;1132;033;15;05;172;08;1133;035;130;01;150;08;1131;037;180;08;1131;043;174;09;1129;047;14;02;163;08;12;01;1129;047;169;06;1133;048;169;06;11;02;1130;051;165;01;12;05;11;01;1129;059;158;01;12;03;1132;060;162;01;1133;060;162;01;1132;062;12;01;1190;063;12;02;159;02;1127;064;117;01;1173;066;1189;069;1142;02;13;02;137;075;1137;08;134;077;1138;08;132;078;1140;05;132;079;158;01;182;05;131;082;1126;01;112;03;131;083;1125;03;111;05;130;083;1124;04;111;03;131;086;1121;05;110;04;130;086;1123;04;19;04;130;083;1126;05;19;03;130;083;1125;01;11;05;18;05;128;083;1126;06;110;04;129;082;1126;06;112;01;130;084;119;01;173;01;129;06;140;01;14;083;117;01;1105;05;140;02;13;082;177;01;11;01;15;01;11;01;135;07;138;088;177;01;15;04;136;07;137;089;184;02;18;01;128;06;138;01;11;086;171;01;122;02;129;01;123;01;11;01;116;01;11;085;11;01;110;02;158;02;121;02;153;01;11;01;115;02;11;085;11;01;12;010;160;01;174;04;115;089;13;010;159;01;173;06;115;0101;110;01;149;01;150;01;122;06;14;03;17;099;163;01;18;01;140;02;123;06;12;05;16;098;173;02;139;03;122;015;13;096;12;01;17;01;156;02;11;01;15;01;140;03;122;017;11;096;12;01;17;01;157;01;11;01;136;01;13;02;14;04;122;0116;17;01;157;02;136;01;13;03;14;04;122;0116;17;01;158;01;14;01;131;01;14;02;14;04;122;0121;11;02;156;01;110;02;123;03;13;011;122;0125;189;05;15;09;123;0121;11;02;172;01;118;03;14;01;11;05;11;03;124;0119;163;01;132;01;15;07;11;02;127;0120;161;02;11;01;125;01;17;011;128;0122;153;01;13;04;124;01;13;01;12;01;12;011;129;0121;12;01;148;02;16;02;134;011;131;0119;12;01;145;02;13;01;15;01;131;01;14;010;132;05;13;0109;14;02;11;02;148;01;133;04;15;07;147;0102;13;02;12;01;148;03;131;05;14;08;151;098;11;07;148;03;129;05;11;01;15;07;152;0102;14;01;137;012;128;06;11;01;14;08;152;03;11;098;135;024;113;01;17;011;13;08;144;01;13;01;12;04;13;097;12;01;12;01;129;023;119;013;12;09;144;01;13;01;12;04;15;0102;12;02;16;02;114;025;111;03;13;05;11;020;144;01;13;01;11;05;15;0118;12;036;13;01;11;01;12;010;11;022;143;01;13;01;11;05;15;0200;136;01;17;01;11;05;12;0203;136;01;17;01;11;05;12;0204;135;01;17;07;11;0206;142;07;11;0208;14;03;129;02;13;0216;19;01;12;01;122;01;14;01;12;0215;15;02;11;01;124;01;13;01;13;01;13;0212;15;02;125;01;17;01;14;0213;134;02;16;08;13;0204;125;01;13;01;13;03;15;05;16;0209;118;04;12;03;11;04;14;06;14;088;155;025;162;02;124;06;</fow>
      <midmap>False</midmap>
      <npcs></npcs>
      <spawners>
        <spawner>
          <uniqueId>NPC_m2001_Dorsey_Intro_Bot</uniqueId>
          <npcActive>True</npcActive>
        </spawner>
```

into

```
save><version>0.6</version><currentScene>ar_0000_WorldMap</currentScene><saveTime>20200920T08:06:13+2</saveTime><gameplaytime>0</gameplaytime><difficulty>3</difficulty><ironManMode>False</ironManMode><permanentDeath>False</permanentDeath><hideSkillRequirements>False</hideSkillRequirements><friendlyFire>True</friendlyFire><cameraZoom>0</cameraZoom><selectedPc>0</selectedPc><time>0</time><money>666</money><levels><level><name>ar_m2001_AmbushSite</name><fow>148;0208;11;08;15;0242;11;0255;11;0255;11;04;126;01;14;0220;11;04;132;0219;11;03;133;0219;11;03;132;0220;11;02;133;0220;11;02;131;0222;11;02;131;0222;11;02;132;0221;135;0221;136;0220;12;02;11;01;129;0221;11;03;131;0221;132;02;12;0220;132;02;12;0220;132;02;11;0221;132;0224;131;012;18;0205;131;012;15;0208;131;012;15;0208;130;013;15;0208;11;03;120;019;16;0207;11;03;120;01;14;014;14;0209;11;03;120;01;13;015;14;0209;11;03;120;01;12;016;14;0209;11;03;117;04;12;015;162;01;16;0145;11;03;117;04;11;015;171;0144;11;04;115;01;12;017;14;05;155;0152;11;05;110;023;15;04;11;03;16;02;144;08;11;0143;11;03;18;026;175;0143;11;03;14;02;12;025;177;0142;11;03;14;028;178;0142;11;03;14;027;174;01;14;0142;11;03;14;026;117;01;157;01;15;0141;11;03;14;026;175;01;15;0141;11;03;14;025;182;0141;12;02;14;024;177;01;16;0140;13;01;18;020;177;01;16;0140;13;01;18;019;178;01;16;0140;13;01;18;019;178;01;16;0140;13;01;18;018;186;0140;13;01;112;014;186;0140;13;01;112;013;187;0142;11;01;112;013;187;0144;112;013;187;0145;17;016;188;0148;14;016;188;0168;188;0168;188;0167;112;02;11;02;172;0167;18;01;11;03;13;01;172;0167;18;03;14;02;171;0168;115;02;171;0168;16;03;179;0168;16;03;178;046;112;0111;18;01;178;040;118;0111;188;036;121;0111;19;01;12;01;175;033;123;05;11;013;11;092;16;04;12;01;175;031;126;04;11;013;12;091;18;02;12;01;175;029;126;06;18;06;12;091;18;02;178;027;142;06;12;091;19;01;16;01;171;026;142;07;12;011;12;078;116;01;171;024;144;07;12;010;14;076;117;01;171;023;145;08;11;09;16;075;189;022;147;07;11;09;17;073;190;020;149;07;11;08;19;072;190;018;152;06;11;07;111;070;191;016;154;01;12;03;11;07;112;069;191;015;158;02;12;06;113;068;19;01;182;013;166;04;114;067;19;01;182;012;167;03;116;066;19;02;180;012;159;01;12;02;123;065;12;02;188;011;160;01;12;02;122;066;192;010;160;02;12;02;121;067;192;09;163;04;119;068;192;09;145;03;116;04;119;068;192;08;146;04;111;01;13;04;117;070;192;07;146;07;17;03;12;05;115;072;116;01;174;08;145;010;15;03;11;06;113;01;11;072;116;01;174;07;145;026;111;076;147;01;143;06;146;026;12;085;147;01;142;07;146;026;17;083;116;02;126;01;142;07;122;01;122;013;18;06;15;086;114;01;11;01;168;06;11;01;122;01;16;01;119;09;18;07;121;05;11;059;117;02;170;05;120;02;124;02;12;03;116;06;122;02;14;064;111;01;171;06;120;01;13;05;145;02;127;064;114;01;168;05;120;03;11;02;11;02;16;01;112;01;126;02;127;064;114;01;167;06;119;07;118;05;126;02;11;01;125;059;11;01;11;01;128;01;153;06;115;014;147;02;11;01;125;059;132;01;126;01;126;06;18;01;13;03;12;06;11;03;115;02;132;02;11;01;125;058;115;01;117;01;115;01;110;01;125;07;17;03;11;04;12;04;121;02;132;02;11;01;125;057;134;01;127;03;121;07;18;03;11;07;11;01;121;03;132;02;11;01;125;057;118;02;114;01;127;03;120;08;18;03;11;08;15;01;115;02;134;02;11;01;125;056;118;01;135;01;130;09;18;03;11;03;13;02;17;01;148;04;120;03;13;056;117;02;136;01;128;09;19;03;12;02;13;05;13;03;146;04;121;05;11;055;156;01;127;010;19;03;12;010;13;03;147;03;121;05;11;055;134;01;148;011;19;03;12;010;13;03;148;03;120;05;11;054;184;011;110;02;12;09;11;01;11;02;11;01;149;02;13;077;116;01;136;02;129;011;112;01;11;011;155;01;16;074;115;01;136;02;130;011;116;09;164;071;152;01;132;011;117;08;158;01;11;02;12;071;115;01;136;01;132;011;117;06;15;01;158;01;15;02;11;064;152;01;132;011;117;07;13;02;159;01;14;066;153;01;132;011;121;03;13;01;161;02;12;066;153;01;132;011;122;03;11;03;12;01;157;03;11;04;12;060;185;012;123;09;159;06;14;058;152;01;132;012;122;010;160;05;15;057;151;01;133;012;121;011;161;04;14;058;151;01;132;013;121;011;161;05;13;058;151;01;132;013;120;012;162;05;12;058;183;015;119;012;162;016;11;048;183;015;117;014;163;015;11;048;111;01;170;017;115;010;12;03;163;015;11;048;111;02;169;017;113;012;14;01;161;01;12;014;11;048;111;02;134;01;133;018;112;014;14;01;11;02;157;066;110;03;133;02;133;019;110;016;13;03;11;01;156;066;110;03;133;02;132;020;110;016;13;04;16;02;149;066;110;02;134;02;132;021;15;01;13;011;11;011;11;01;15;01;153;061;111;02;134;02;131;022;12;01;11;03;11;012;12;03;11;03;164;061;111;01;136;02;129;045;13;01;12;01;164;060;150;01;129;044;173;059;179;035;121;01;16;02;156;056;166;02;111;035;129;02;157;053;168;01;111;035;124;01;14;02;159;08;11;042;165;01;115;034;113;03;113;02;161;049;159;04;13;02;114;033;130;01;162;047;159;06;11;02;116;032;130;01;164;045;160;05;11;01;118;032;121;01;173;044;160;05;121;031;198;040;163;01;13;03;117;031;1100;038;169;02;117;031;1101;036;169;03;117;030;1103;034;132;01;136;03;117;030;1104;033;170;03;117;030;1105;031;171;01;117;031;1106;030;119;01;152;01;118;029;1107;029;131;01;141;01;115;025;119;01;194;028;131;01;158;021;123;03;192;027;131;01;157;019;128;01;193;026;131;01;157;017;129;01;195;025;131;01;158;01;12;011;1127;025;190;02;11;09;1130;024;193;08;1132;023;191;08;1134;023;191;07;1136;022;127;01;164;05;1137;022;127;01;165;03;1139;021;126;02;165;02;1140;022;126;01;1208;021;126;01;1208;021;126;02;1207;021;126;02;1208;020;126;02;1208;020;126;02;191;01;1116;020;126;02;1209;019;126;02;1209;019;116;01;19;03;1208;019;115;04;17;04;11;01;172;02;1131;019;116;04;17;03;13;01;171;01;1131;019;118;02;18;02;13;04;168;01;1132;019;117;02;116;03;164;01;1134;019;117;02;182;03;1133;019;117;02;180;06;1132;020;116;01;178;09;1132;020;116;02;176;05;11;08;1128;020;120;01;171;08;11;01;12;03;12;01;18;02;1116;021;119;01;154;03;114;04;11;02;16;02;12;01;18;02;1116;021;119;03;154;01;114;04;11;03;115;01;1120;022;118;03;150;02;117;08;1136;022;120;01;170;01;11;04;1137;023;119;05;143;01;123;03;117;01;1121;023;120;05;143;01;123;02;1139;024;123;02;142;01;123;02;1139;025;121;02;169;02;1137;025;128;01;161;04;1137;026;177;02;110;05;1135;028;188;04;1136;029;186;01;1140;030;185;02;1138;032;184;02;11;05;1132;033;15;05;172;08;1133;035;130;01;150;08;1131;037;180;08;1131;043;174;09;1129;047;14;02;163;08;12;01;1129;047;169;06;1133;048;169;06;11;02;1130;051;165;01;12;05;11;01;1129;059;158;01;12;03;1132;060;162;01;1133;060;162;01;1132;062;12;01;1190;063;12;02;159;02;1127;064;117;01;1173;066;1189;069;1142;02;13;02;137;075;1137;08;134;077;1138;08;132;078;1140;05;132;079;158;01;182;05;131;082;1126;01;112;03;131;083;1125;03;111;05;130;083;1124;04;111;03;131;086;1121;05;110;04;130;086;1123;04;19;04;130;083;1126;05;19;03;130;083;1125;01;11;05;18;05;128;083;1126;06;110;04;129;082;1126;06;112;01;130;084;119;01;173;01;129;06;140;01;14;083;117;01;1105;05;140;02;13;082;177;01;11;01;15;01;11;01;135;07;138;088;177;01;15;04;136;07;137;089;184;02;18;01;128;06;138;01;11;086;171;01;122;02;129;01;123;01;11;01;116;01;11;085;11;01;110;02;158;02;121;02;153;01;11;01;115;02;11;085;11;01;12;010;160;01;174;04;115;089;13;010;159;01;173;06;115;0101;110;01;149;01;150;01;122;06;14;03;17;099;163;01;18;01;140;02;123;06;12;05;16;098;173;02;139;03;122;015;13;096;12;01;17;01;156;02;11;01;15;01;140;03;122;017;11;096;12;01;17;01;157;01;11;01;136;01;13;02;14;04;122;0116;17;01;157;02;136;01;13;03;14;04;122;0116;17;01;158;01;14;01;131;01;14;02;14;04;122;0121;11;02;156;01;110;02;123;03;13;011;122;0125;189;05;15;09;123;0121;11;02;172;01;118;03;14;01;11;05;11;03;124;0119;163;01;132;01;15;07;11;02;127;0120;161;02;11;01;125;01;17;011;128;0122;153;01;13;04;124;01;13;01;12;01;12;011;129;0121;12;01;148;02;16;02;134;011;131;0119;12;01;145;02;13;01;15;01;131;01;14;010;132;05;13;0109;14;02;11;02;148;01;133;04;15;07;147;0102;13;02;12;01;148;03;131;05;14;08;151;098;11;07;148;03;129;05;11;01;15;07;152;0102;14;01;137;012;128;06;11;01;14;08;152;03;11;098;135;024;113;01;17;011;13;08;144;01;13;01;12;04;13;097;12;01;12;01;129;023;119;013;12;09;144;01;13;01;12;04;15;0102;12;02;16;02;114;025;111;03;13;05;11;020;144;01;13;01;11;05;15;0118;12;036;13;01;11;01;12;010;11;022;143;01;13;01;11;05;15;0200;136;01;17;01;11;05;12;0203;136;01;17;01;11;05;12;0204;135;01;17;07;11;0206;142;07;11;0208;14;03;129;02;13;0216;19;01;12;01;122;01;14;01;12;0215;15;02;11;01;124;01;13;01;13;01;13;0212;15;02;125;01;17;01;14;0213;134;02;16;08;13;0204;125;01;13;01;13;03;15;05;16;0209;118;04;12;03;11;04;14;06;14;088;155;025;162;02;124;06;</fow><midmap>False</midmap><npcs></npcs><spawners><spawner><uniqueId>NPC_m2001_Dorsey_Intro_Bot</uniqueId><npcActive>True</npcActive></spawner>
```

is there anything that will do this? like cat 1.txt --someattributes > 2.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html). One of the following:

```
tr -d '\n '
tr -d '\r\n '
tr -d '\r\n[:space:]'
```

or similar, depending on what exactly you mean by "linebreaks & spaces". The tool does not accept a filename as an argument, it only reads its stdin. Proceed like this:

```
tr -d '\n ' <1.txt >2.txt
```

Notes:

- `tr` is quite straightforward. Spaces (if any) inside `<>` will also be deleted.
- Even if `1.txt` is a text file, the output file will (most likely) not be a [text file in terms of POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403). Unless empty, it will contain an [incomplete line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195) only (compare: [line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206)). You can add a terminating newline character on the fly like this:

  ```
  { tr -d '\n '; echo; } <1.txt >2.txt
  ```

  <sup>You may want to add some logic and suppress `echo` iff the input file is empty; or iff the output from `tr` is empty (these two conditions are not equivalent). I won't elaborate.</sup>

  Still if the output (including the added newline character) exceeds `{LINE_MAX}` bytes, then formally `2.txt` will not be a text file, so text processing utilities may not work with it.